# Deploying Websphere Portals onto a 6.1 Server

Tags: deployment, rad, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

Any time I try to publish my Portal project on a Websphere Portal 6.1 Server, I get the following error message:

```
Portal project publishing is not supported on WebSphere Portal v6.1 Server
```

Is that really true or have I done something wrong?

I'm trying to deploy a portal project, with the underlying goal of publishing a new theme.

Unfortunately, any time I try to deploy, I get the error message listed above from the IDE and no errors in the console.

The RAD version is 7.0.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will help, but:

> Limitation: Although the WebSphere
>   Portal installer contains an advanced
>   option to install an empty portal,
>   Portal Designer relies on
>   administration portlets for setting
>   access control; therefore, publishing
>   a portal project to an empty portal is
>   not supported.

Are you trying to deploy a portlet or an entire portal project? What version of RAD are you using? Any other information in the error log? (Both within RAD & on WP server) Is the error message posted verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deploy such a project to a WebSphere Portal. I use v6.2 and deploy portlets, which are parts of a big Portal project, every day. I'm only a starter in such a stuff, but I can say that WebSphere is really buggy. You know, it is a big difference to run a deployed app "locally, in a workspace" or "on a server". I suggest you to work out with server options - administrative console.